# Pass environment --dev in angular ng build command dockerfile

Tags: angular, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

Need guidance on how to pass environment --dev in angular ng build command dockerfile
the dockerfile has following line

### Build the angular app in production mode and store the artifacts in dist folder

RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist

how can we pass --prod as a variable in this docker file which can be picked up by cloud build?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question, does `RUN npm run ng build -- --prod --output-path=dist` not work? do you want to pass `--prod` or `--dev`?

Comment: By `--dev` I believe you meant `--configuration="dev"`, as `--prod` is an alias of `--configuration="production"` but `--dev` is not an alias. You can refer to this documentation: https://angular.io/cli/build

Comment: Can you share your current dockerfile and what you want to achieve?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, you are trying to pass `--dev` or `--prod` as a variable? Could you share your docker file?